# Regular expression find and replace

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I have a really poorly formatted XML file and I am looking to replace the names of some of the tags.

For example...

```
<column name="id">1</column>
```

should become

```
<id>1</id>
```

I have over 7000 entries and don't fancy doing this by hand.  I am using Dreamweaver's Find & Replace.  Obviously the value "1" in the example is a dynamic value.

Cheers for any help...

Comment: If you have some knowledge of XSLT, it could be done with a stylesheet (I dare not say "simple", I have never managed to write one in less than 30 minutes...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find:

```
<column name="id">(\d+)</column>
```

Replace with

```
<id>$1</id>
```

Make sure you check *Use regular expression* in the dialog box.

[See further on Adobe's site](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt2.html).

Comment: More likely, the OP was looking for `<column name="([^"]+)">(\d+)</column>` to be replaced by `<$1>$2</$1>`, but the direction looks correct.

Comment: You are both correct. Thanks for the accurate and speedy reply guys.

Comment: Yep, generalizing with the above solution looks like the way to go

Comment: Taking it one step further, I suppose `<column name="([^"]+)">([^<])</column>` replaced with `<$1>$2</$1>` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Search for: `<column name="id">(.*)</column>` 
Replace with: `<id>\1</id>`

Answer (score 0):

A simple python solution, probably easier using Perl:

```
import re        # regular expression
import sys       # command line arguments

pat = re.compile(r'<column name=\"id\">(\d*)</column>', re.IGNORECASE)

if __name__=='__main__':
    filename = sys.argv[1]

     for line in open(filename):
         matchObj = pat.search(line)
         if matchObj != None:
             s"<id>" + matchObj.group(1) + "</id>"
         else:
             print line
```